# How to transfer value from one python script class to another python script

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I need to connect two python script class to each other and transfer values.
It seems that I made some mistakes to initialize the class objects and passing the 
values please note the way I followed and somebody please kindly advise me on where I am getting wrong.

what is wrong with this line of code

```
def TransferTreeVal(objSubS):

    objCM=MainScript.clsMain()
    print "Transfer value"
```

Some more detailed code

```
##MainScript.py

import os
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
class clsMain():

    def __init__ (objCM):

        root['width']=500
        root['height']=400
        root['bg']='brown'
        objCM.MethodDisplay()


    def MethodDisplay(objCM):

       print "display windows"


root=tk.Tk()
objCM = clsMain()
root.mainloop()


##SubScript.py 

import os
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

import MainScript

class clsSubS():

    def __init__ (objSubS):

        root['width']=500
        root['height']=500
        root['bg']='brown'
        objSubS.DispWin()

    def TransferTreeVal(objSubS):

        objCM=MainScript.clsMain()
        print "Transfer value"


root=tk.Tk()
objSubS = clsSubS()
```

Comment: The format of your question is messed up. Some of your code isn't highlighted properly.

Comment: @Bryan, Thanks a lot for looking into my question, as you said I just tried to indented the code so I believe it is readable. Could you now please try to answer? please let me know if anything else I have to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you are doing wrong is that you are importing files that have executable code in them. When you import SubScript.py, it is going to execute the code at the bottom which creates an instance of `Tk`. However, your main script also creates an instance of `Tk` and you should only ever have a single instance in a running program.

Normally, if you have a class you want to import, but you also want to use it as a standalone script, you "hide" the standalone script code behind a check like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    objSubS = clsSubS()
```

With that, the code will only get executed if you do `python SubScript.py`. Also, when you import SubScript, that code will *not* run.

Comment: @Brayan, Really Appreciate for helping me, let me try this solution now it bit confusing to me